# Number of steps in escalator : Time, Speed and Distance Problem

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math

> An escalator is moving downwards with a speed of $4$ steps per minute.
> A person takes $6$ minutes less to get down if he is coming down on
> the moving escalator as compared to when he comes down via the
> stationary escalator. Another person takes $6$ minutes more to get up
> if he is going up on the moving escalator as compared to when he goes
> up via the stationary escalator. If they start together from the top
> and the bottom respectively, they meet after $4$ minutes on the moving
> escalator. How many steps are there in the escalator?

My solution approach :- 
Let the total steps in the escalator be $x$.
Let the speed of the persone be $p$ steps/minute.
Escalator speed = $4$ steps/minute.

In the case of coming down and as per the question :-
$\frac{x}{p}-\frac{x}{p+4}=6$

In the case of going up and as per the question :-
$\frac{x}{p-4}-\frac{x}{p}=6$

Equating both the above equations, we get ;
$\frac{x}{p}-\frac{x}{p+4}=\frac{x}{p-4}-\frac{x}{p}$
$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{p+4}=\frac{1}{p-4}-\frac{1}{p} \text{ (Cancelling out $x$ from both sides.)}$
$\Rightarrow \frac{2}{p}=\frac{1}{p-4}+\frac{1}{p+4} $
$\Rightarrow p^2=p^2-16$
which doesn't lead to any solution. What am I doing wrong? Is there any different concept that is used in escalator's problem. I was trying to use the concepts that I learnt in boat and stream problems. 
Also the last bit of information that has been given in the problem i.e. " If they start together from the top and the bottom respectively, they meet after $4$ minutes on the moving escalator." doesn't come to use in my solution approach. 
Please help me on this !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Nowhere does it say that the rates of different people are the same. Especially one stomps up and the other stomps down.

Comment: ohh..ok...my bad..lemme try this question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve,

$\frac{x}{p}-\frac{x}{p+4} = \frac{x}{q-4}-\frac{x}{q} = 6$

$\implies \frac{2x}{p(p+4)} = \frac{2x}{q(q-4)} = 3 \tag1$

$\frac{y}{p+4} = \frac{x-y}{q-4}= 4 \tag2$

where $x$ is total number of steps in the escalator, $y$ is number of steps from top where both persons meet, $p$ is the speed of the person coming down the escalator in steps per minute and $q$ is the speed of the person going up the escalator.

Solving both, we get $x = 48$.